# Como aplicar diferentes estilos a los items de un ListView?

Tags: android, android-studio, sms

estoy realizando mi aplicacion en la que debo trabajar con las llamadas y mensajes del telefono, las cuales son almacenadas en una base de datos y son retornadas por medio de AssyncTask, lo que necesito lograr es que en una misma lista se muestren ambas consultas, logré hacerlo pero ahora como puedo hacer que cada una se muestre con diferente diseño?

Item

```
public class Item {
private String nombre;
private String numero;
private String  fecha;
private String duracion;
private String tipo;

public Item() {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.numero = numero;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.duracion = duracion;
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getDuracion() {
    return duracion;
}

public void setDuracion(String duracion) {
    this.duracion = duracion;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
}
```

Adaptador

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> arrayList;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Random random;


public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> arrayList){
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    random = new Random();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_llamadas, null);
    }

    ImageView iv_main = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_main);
    TextView nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    ImageView tv_main = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_main);
    TextView fecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
    TextView duracion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duracion);
    TextView tipo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tipo);

    nombre.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNombre());
    fecha.setText(arrayList.get(position).getFecha());
    duracion.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDuracion());
    tipo.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTipo());
    iv_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
    int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250));
    iv_main.setColorFilter(color);
    tv_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp);




    return convertView;
}
}
```

Fragment

```
public class ActivityOne extends Fragment {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView lista_mostrando;
Adapter adaptador;
static ArrayList<Item> lista;
View view;

public static ActivityOne newInstance() {
    ActivityOne fragment = new  ActivityOne();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    lista = new ArrayList<>();


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_one, container, false);
    lista_mostrando = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista_llamadas);

    new Llamadas().execute();
    new Mensajes().execute();


    return view;
}


private class Llamadas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        String datoNombreContacto = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("contacto_detalle");
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/xampp/BdApp/consultar_llamadas.php?nombre=" + datoNombreContacto;
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
                    String nombre = c.getString("nombre");
                    String fecha = c.getString("fecha");
                    String duracion = c.getString("duracion");
                    String tipo = c.getString("tipo");



                    Item e=new Item();
                    e.setNombre(nombre);
                    e.setFecha(fecha);
                    e.setDuracion(duracion);
                    e.setTipo(tipo);

                    lista.add(e);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Esta habiendo problemas para cargar el JSON");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        adaptador = new Adapter(getActivity(),lista);
        lista_mostrando.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }


}

private class Mensajes extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        String datoNumeroContacto = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("numero_detalle");
        String url2 = "http://10.0.2.2/xampp/BdApp/consultar_mensajes.php?numero=" + datoNumeroContacto;
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url2);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
                    String fecha = c.getString("fecha");
                    String tipo = c.getString("tipo");



                    Item e=new Item();
                    e.setFecha(fecha);
                    e.setTipo(tipo);

                    lista.add(e);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Esta habiendo problemas para cargar el JSON");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        adaptador = new Adapter(getActivity(),lista);
        lista_mostrando.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }


}


}
```

Así es como se ve la lista actualmente, como se puede notar en la imagen tanto las llamadas como los mensajes se despliegan de la misma manera, dejando espacios en blanco para los mensajes en el campo de duracion (ya que no tienen duracion) como se puede ver en la parte inferior, por ello necesito dar un estilo diferente a los mensajes para evitar esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Primero

Estas creando dos adaptadores, uno en el AsyncTask `Llamadas` y otro en el AsyncTask `Mensajes`. Cuando ejecutas el AsyncTask `Llamadas`, en el primer adaptador que creas (en el método `onPostExecute()`) le pasas los datos de las llamadas almacenados en el `ArrayList lista`. Y cuando ejecutas el AsyncTask `Mensajes`, en el adaptador "que estas creando de nuevo" en el método `onPostExecute()` le pasas los datos de las llamadas y los mensajes almacenados en el  `ArrayList lista`.

Ten en cuenta que en el  `ArrayList lista` estas almacenando los datos de la llamadas y también los datos de los mensajes. En el AsyncTask `Llamadas` almacenas las llamadas y en el AsyncTask "Mensajes" agregas los mensajes.

Gráficamente se podría ver de la siguiente forma:

```
ArrayList lista

AsyncTask Llamadas {

    lista.add(llamada 1) 
    lista.add(llamada 2)
    lista.add(llamada 3)

    // Si imprimes la lista obtendrás:
    llamada 1
    llamada 2
    llamada 3
}

AsyncTask Mensajes {

    lista.add(mensaje 1)
    lista.add(mensaje 2)
    lista.add(mensaje 3)

    // Si imprimes la lista obtendrás:
    llamada 1
    llamada 2
    llamada 3
    mensaje 1
    mensaje 2
    mensaje 3
}
```

El adaptador que muestra los datos en el ListView es el que se crea en el método `onPostExecute()` del AsyncTask `Mensajes`. Al final, el adaptador que creas en el método `onPostExecute()` del AsyncTask `Llamadas` no lo estas utilizando, por lo que no tiene sentido crear ese adaptador.

La implementación de tu código puede mejorar, no es necesario que crees dos AsyncTask, ni que crees dos adaptadores. Con un solo AsyncTask es suficiente. Pero bueno, eso es algo que te explicare al final.

---

### Solucion

Volviendo al problema, tienes que declarar una variable en tu clase `Item`, en esta variable se almacenara el id que identificara las llamadas y los mensajes.

#### Item

```
public class Item {

    // variable que almacena el id que identifica las 
    // llamadas o los mensajes
    private String idGroup; 

    private String nombre;
    private String numero;
    private String fecha;
    private String duracion;
    private String tipo;

    public Item() {    
        this.idGroup = idGroup;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.duracion = duracion;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getIdGroup () {
        return idGroup;
    }

    public void setIdGroup (String idGroup) {
        this.idGroup = idGroup;
    }
}
```

#### AsyncTask

Ahora bien, en tus AsyncTask dependiendo de si estas obteniendo los datos de las llamadas o de los mensajes, a la variable `idGroup` le asignas una valor diferente. Los valores pueden ser por ejemplo: "llamadas" en el caso de las llamadas y "mensajes " en el caso de los mensajes.

El adaptador solo lo tienes que crear en el AsyncTask `Mensajes`, ya que hay es donde tienes almacenados en el  `ArrayList lista` los datos de las llamadas y los mensajes. Recuerda que en el AsyncTask `Llamadas` solo almacenas en el `ArrayList lista` los datos de las llamadas

```
private class Llamadas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        ...

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
                    String idGroup = "llamadas" // Id de las llamadas
                    String nombre = c.getString("nombre");
                    String fecha = c.getString("fecha");
                    String duracion = c.getString("duracion");
                    String tipo = c.getString("tipo");

                    Item e=new Item();
                    e.setIdGroup(idGroup) // Asignas el id
                    e.setNombre(nombre);
                    e.setFecha(fecha);
                    e.setDuracion(duracion);
                    e.setTipo(tipo);

                    lista.add(e);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ...

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ...

        // Los datos se pasaran al adaptador creado en el método onPostExecute()
        // del AsynTask Llamadas ⬇. 
    }
}

private class Mensajes extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        ...

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
                    String idGroup = "mensajes"; // Id de los mensajes
                    String fecha = c.getString("fecha");
                    String tipo = c.getString("tipo");

                    Item e=new Item();
                    e.setIdGroup(idGroup); // Asignas el id
                    e.setFecha(fecha);
                    e.setTipo(tipo);

                    lista.add(e);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ...

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ...

        adaptador = new Adapter(getActivity(),lista);
        lista_mostrando.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
}
```

#### Adaptador

En tu adaptador evalúas el valor de la variable `idGroup` y dependiendo del valor de esta, le asignas un estilo diferente a los items.

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> arrayList;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Random random;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> arrayList){
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        random = new Random();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_llamadas, null);
        }

        ImageView iv_main = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_main);
        TextView nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        ImageView tv_main = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_main);
        TextView fecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        TextView duracion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duracion);
        TextView tipo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tipo);

        // Obtienes el valor de la variable idGroup
        String idGroup = arrayList.get(position).getIdGroup();

        // Evalúa si los datos son de las llamadas
        if (idGroup.equals("llamadas")) {

            nombre.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNombre());
            fecha.setText(arrayList.get(position).getFecha());
            duracion.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDuracion());
            tipo.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTipo());
            iv_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
            int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250));
            iv_main.setColorFilter(color);
            tv_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp);

        } else if (idGroup.equals("mensajes")) { // Evalúa si los datos son de los mensajes

            // Aquí le asignas un valor diferente a los items de los mensajes. No se,
            // puede ser un color de fondo diferente o un icono diferente. Por ejemplo
            // yo modificare el color de fondo de los TextView, y al ImageView le 
            // asignare una imagen diferente.
            nombre.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNombre());
            fecha.setText(arrayList.get(position).getFecha());
            duracion.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDuracion());
            tipo.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTipo());
            iv_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
            int color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250));
            iv_main.setColorFilter(color);

            // Se modifica la imagen del ImageView. La imagen que he colocado en una imagen
            // de los recursos de Android.
            tv_main.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);

            // El color de fondo de los TextView se modifican a gris
            nombre.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            fecha.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
            duracion.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
            tipo.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

            // Lo que te recomiendo es que modifiques el color de fondo del layout que
            // utilizas como plantilla de los items. EL layout que contienes los
            // TextView y los ImageView que modificas aquí.
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

---

#### Como mejorar tu implementación

En este [ejemplo](https://gist.github.com/david-minaya/5185b01a2a9ff2a825c1a52e323719c5) explico como mejorar la implementación de tu código.

Comment: hola, gracias por la ayuda, lo probé y no he podido solucionar el problema. Ahora toda la lista toma los atributos de la clave "mensaje" y no da error alguno. Tienes alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: @flo           He editado mi respuesta, pruebala y me dejas saber.

Comment: Funciono de maravilla, muchisimas gracias !!

Comment: Recuerda que aparte de marcar las respuestas como **aceptada** también puedes darle un **voto a favor**, tal como se explica en el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) de Stack Overflow en español. Si te interesa saber como mejorar la implementacion de tu codigo te invito a que entres al [ejemplo](https://gist.github.com/david-minaya/5185b01a2a9ff2a825c1a52e323719c5) que he creado.